# How to use old style numbers from the GFS Didot font family?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, oldstylenums

I am using pdfLaTeX and the gfsdidot package for my document.

According to the [documentation](https://texlive.mycozy.space/fonts/greek/gfs/gfsdidot/doc/GFSDidot-LaTeX-Guide.pdf),

> The package provides also a matching small caps shape for both latin and greek including old style numbers.

I read a lot of related questions on this website, but I didn't find how to use old style digits for the whole document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
123
\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't look as if the package implement a default osf-option. You get old style numbers only if you use \scshape or \oldstylenums{123}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there a way to apply oldstylenums to all numbers without messing with active characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run it with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFSDidot}[
   Extension = .otf,
  Numbers = OldStyle,
  BoldFont = *Bold,
  ItalicFont = *Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldItalic,
]
\begin{document}
    0123456789
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With your code, \textbf does not longer work

Comment: See edited code ...